# Use dancers with Miktex

Tags: fonts

How to type the dancing men code in LaTeX with MiTex on windows compile with Texmaker.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\DeclareFontFamily{OT1}{dancers}{}
\DeclareFontShape{OT1}{dancers}{m}{n}{
<->  gen * dancers}{}
\begin{document}
\usefont{OT1}{dancers}{}{}\spaceskip=3pt
T~h~e ~ Q~u~i~c~k ~ B~r~o~w~n ~ F~o~x ~ J~u~m~p~s ~ O~v~e~r ~ T~h~e ~ L~a~z~y ~ D~o~g
\end{document}
```

I use xeLaTex by the way. Here is my log file.

```
This is XeTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-0.9999.3 (MiKTeX 2.9) (preloaded format=xelatex 2014.1.18) 13 OCT 2014 10:15
entering extended mode
**1.tex
(D:\LaTeX讀書會\1.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <v3.8m> and hyphenation patterns for english, afrikaans, ancientgreek, ar
abic, armenian, assamese, basque, bengali, bokmal, bulgarian, catalan, coptic,
croatian, czech, danish, dutch, esperanto, estonian, farsi, finnish, french, ga
lician, german, german-x-2013-05-26, greek, gujarati, hindi, hungarian, iceland
ic, indonesian, interlingua, irish, italian, kannada, kurmanji, latin, latvian,
lithuanian, malayalam, marathi, mongolian, mongolianlmc, monogreek, ngerman, n
german-x-2013-05-26, nynorsk, oriya, panjabi, pinyin, polish, portuguese, roman
ian, russian, sanskrit, serbian, slovak, slovenian, spanish, swedish, swissgerm
an, tamil, telugu, turkish, turkmen, ukenglish, ukrainian, uppersorbian, usengl
ishmax, welsh, loaded.
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\minimal.cls"
Document Class: minimal 2001/05/25 Standard LaTeX minimal class
) (D:\LaTeX讀書會\1.aux)
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 5.
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `OT1/dancers//' undefined
(Font) using `OT1/dancers/m/n' instead on input line 6.
Requested font "dancers10" at 10.0pt
! Font OT1/dancers/m/n/10=dancers10 at 10.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file o
r installed font not found.
<to be read again>
relax
l.6 \usefont{OT1}{dancers}{}{}
\spaceskip=3pt
I wasn't able to read the size data for this font,
so I will ignore the font specification.
[Wizards can fix TFM files using TFtoPL/PLtoTF.]
You might try inserting a different font spec;
e.g., type `I\font<same font id>=<substitute font name>'.
-> font not found, using "nullfont"
Missing character: There is no T in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no h in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no e in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no Q in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no u in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no i in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no c in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no k in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no B in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no r in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no o in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no w in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no n in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no F in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no o in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no x in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no J in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no u in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no m in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no p in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no s in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no O in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no v in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no e in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no r in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no T in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no h in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no e in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no L in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no a in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no z in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no y in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no D in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no o in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no g in font nullfont!
[1] (D:\LaTeX讀書會\1.aux)
LaTeX Font Warning: Some font shapes were not available, defaults substituted.
)
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
26 strings out of 429025
320 string characters out of 3166798
47509 words of memory out of 3000000
3377 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+200000
3640 words of font info for 14 fonts, out of 3000000 for 9000
912 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
16i,4n,12p,139b,92s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s
Output written on 1.pdf (1 page).
```

Comment: It compiles OK here with pdfLaTeX but I can't manage to view it if I use LaTeX to compile to DVI.

Comment: I use xeLaTex by the way.

Comment: Works fine with XeLaTeX, too.

Comment: I'm on TeX Live. The package is certainly available for MiKTeX. Are you sure it is installed? What does the console output or log file say?

Comment: ! Font OT1/dancers/m/n/10=dancers10 at 10.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file o
r installed font not found.
<to be read again>
relax
l.6 \usefont{OT1}{dancers}{}{}
\spaceskip=3pt
I wasn't able to read the size data for this font,
so I will ignore the font specification.
[Wizards can fix TFM files using TFtoPL/PLtoTF.]
You might try inserting a different font spec;
e.g., type `I\font<same font id>=<substitute font name>'.
-> font not found, using "nullfont"
Missing character: There is no T in font nullfont!
Missing character: There is no h in font nullfont!

Comment: You need to install the package. Use MiKTeX's package manager. However, I can't help further, I'm afraid. MiKTeX is beyond my ken ;).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the `gen*` in the font declaration: There is no dancers10.mf  and unlike TeXLive miktex seems not to be able to create it on the fly from dancers.mf.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\DeclareFontFamily{OT1}{dancers}{}
\DeclareFontShape{OT1}{dancers}{m}{n}{
<->  dancers}{}
\begin{document}
\usefont{OT1}{dancers}{m}{n}\spaceskip=3pt
T~h~e ~ Q~u~i~c~k ~ B~r~o~w~n ~ F~o~x ~ J~u~m~p~s ~ O~v~e~r ~ T~h~e ~ L~a~z~y ~ D~o~g
\end{document}
```