# scale dancers font

Tags: fonts, fontsize

I would like to use `dancers` font in `beamer`. I've converted [Ulrike's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/206882/1952) to  [Use dancers with Miktex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/206855/use-dancers-with-miktex/206882#206882) into a command and I can write the text I want, but I don't know how to make it larger.

I could use `\resizebox` but the result is not nice.

Can you help me?

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\newcommand{\dancers}[1]{%
    \DeclareFontFamily{OT1}{dancers}{}
    \DeclareFontShape{OT1}{dancers}{m}{n}{<-> dancers}{}
    \usefont{OT1}{dancers}{m}{n}\spaceskip=5pt
    #1}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\centering
\dancers{e~x~a~m~p~l~e}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\fontsize{2in}{3in}\selectfont` ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try it like this: Find `dancers.mf` (in fonts/source/public), make a copy in `fonts/source/...` in some local texmf and call it eg `dancers20.mf`. Update the fndb. Open the mf in your editor and change the mg variable in `dancers20.mf` like this

```
mg:=2.0;    % CHANGE THIS TO GET DIFFERENT SIZES OF FONT (font size = 33*mg pt)
```

Then setup your document like this

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\DeclareFontFamily{OT1}{dancers}{}
\DeclareFontShape{OT1}{dancers}{m}{n}{<-15> dancers <15-> dancers20}{}

\newcommand{\dancers}[1]{{%
    \usefont{OT1}{dancers}{m}{n}\spaceskip=5pt
    #1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\centering
\dancers{e~x~a~m~p~l~e}  \Huge \dancers{e~x~a~m~p~l~e}


\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I admit that I don't understand the code but it worked with `\Huge` but not with `\large`. Would you mind to explain it a little bit? In any case, thank you.

Comment: @Ignasi: there are now two different sizes of the font. The original is used for all font size up to 15pt, the larger is used for all sizes larger than 15pt. If you want more sizes you will have to create dancers15mf, dancers30mf, etc. and then setup ranges like `<15-20> dancers15 <20-30> dancers20 <30->dancers30`